# Execute SSA code

Tags: go, ssa

I have a SSA code in text file it was generated from golang.

**How can I compile this SSA code and execute it?**

P.S I don't have an original go code.

Comment: Currently: you cannot.

Comment: Right Volker, +1. @Geha, please see [Golang forum](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/ssa-to-go-decompiler/9223/2) for more background information.